# Bypassing Hotel Wifi authentication using VPN

Tags: wifi, vpn, openvpn

I'm currently in a hotel with pay per day WiFi, I have have logged into it a couple of times on my phone. I just turned on my VPN before logging in to the WiFi and it seems to have bypassed the hotel WiFi login screen and now I'm also able to use my tablet simultaneously on the network, which is odd as I believe this service is normally restricted to one device. Just curious if anyone can explain how this has happened and if this can be replicated on other pay per use WiFi sevices in other hotels?

Comment: Please confirm that both your phone and tablet are indeed connected to the same access point. Next list the IP addresses that you receive from the same hotel access point. Finally, are you making connections over VPN to the same VPN server from both your phone and tablet? Is it possible that you are unintentionally tethering your tablet to your phone?

Comment: I'm unsure how to check which access points the devices are connecting to, I know the router IP is the same: 172.16.16.1.  I'm connecting to two different servers. Definitely not tethering and I don't think iOS allow you to tether WiFi, only cellular data.

Comment: "replicated on other pay per use WiFi sevices in other hotels?" What VPN solution are you using? Tempted to try it myself.

Comment: I'm using PIA via iOS OpenVPN app.

Comment: I think your question is interesting but there are too many unknowns. My first assumption is that your phone and tablet are not connected to the same AP and you are inadvertently accessing some other free wifi. If iOS, you can view AP by going to Settings --> WiFI. Or, this is a misconfiguration at that hotel's wifi. Normally, you need an active connection before VPN will work - I think that the system should be tracking by your device MAC address - whether or not you are using a VPN should not matter for authorization.

Comment: It's possible they are just blocking ports 80 and 443 for unauthenticated users. Your VPN presumably communicates over a different port and can get around the block. I've seen conference center networks that work like this.